# Mysql. Поле типа set c зачениями, связаннми с полями другой таблицы.

Tags: mysql

**Требуется реализовать связь полей таблиц так, что бы в поле второй таблице мы могли указывать не одно, а несколько значений из первой.**

### Допустим

(для ясности приведу примеры названий таблиц и ячеек на русском языке)

Имеем тиблицу "Люди":

Поля: id, name

Значения:

1. 1 Вася
2. 2 Петя
3. 3 Саша
4. 4 Маша

Так же имеем таблицу "Вечеринки" с полем "Приглашенные-люди" типа set, содержащее список приглашенных людей (их id из таблицы "Люди").

Поясню: в поле "Приглашенные люди" должны мочь добавляться только те идентификаторы, которые присутствуют в таблице "Люди".

### Вопрос

Возможно-ли это реализовать на mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Вы собираетесь модифицировать структуру БД в зависимости от добавления/удаления пользователей? Используйте связь типа MANY_MANY и не трогайте структуру

```
users:
id, name

party:
id, name

party_users_rel
id, user_id (Foreign Key), party_id (Foreign Key)
```

[В обоих случаях в FK желателен ON DELETE CASCADE]

Comment: Спасибо. Меня интересует, возможно ли это реализовать без введения дополнительной таблицы? Если на mysql это не возможно, то возможно ли на каких-то других БД?